# Inserir valor numa coluna C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho que ler uma coluna (que é a chave primaria de uma tabela) e ver se nessa coluna existe o valor de uma variável, se não existir, quero adiciona-lo, se existir, quero seguir em frente. 
Tenho este código, mas ele tenta inserir mesmo se já houver então o programa dá erro porque não pode haver 2 chaves primarias iguais):

```
List<string> valoresExistentes = new List<string>();

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Code FROM ArticleFamily", conn);
                SqlDataReader rd3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd3.HasRows)
                {
                    rd3.Read();   
                    if (group != rd3["Code"].ToString())
                    {
                        if (valoresExistentes.Contains(group))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            valoresExistentes.Add(group);

                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO ArticleFamily(Code, [Desc], IsDefault, IsToWeb, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted, Margin, IsPOSVisible, IsWithArticleCodePrefix, ArticleCodePrefix, ExternalCode, IsSubFamilyRequired)
                                                         VALUES (@code, 'Descrição', 0, 0, 1, @date, 1, @date, 0, 0, 1, 1, @code, 1, 0)", conn);
                            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", group);
                            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: amigo essa variável group vem de onde? qual valor tem nela?

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio Eu tenho um ficheiro xml com informações de produtos (o group é uma delas) e uso um foreach para percorrer todos os produtos e a cada foreach a variável toma valores diferentes.

Comment: mas pensando bem cara, vc quer uma lista sem valores repetidos certo? 
vc nao pode preencher essa lista igual o amigo falou abaixo,  ai na lista terá os valores repetidos, entao vc usa um lista.distinct() entao tera a lista so com os codigos que nao se repetem ai no seu else, vc utiliza essa lista 'limpa' para fazer seus inserts

Comment: Tu tem uma lista de "Codes" e quer ver se essas infos são "Code" da sua ArticleFamily?

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio a lista que eu criei foi para pôr os valores que já foram inseridos, para depois não serem inseridos outra vez

Comment: @Aline não, eu tenho uma variável, quero ver se essa variável existe numa coluna, se não existir, quero inserir lá, se existir, não faz nada.

Comment: o problema e que sua logica esta correta amigo, me parece que o erro esta nesta linha       if (group != rd3["Code"].ToString())

tenta jogar esse rd3["Code"].ToString() em uma variável antes do if e ver os valores qeu ele vai retornando enquanto voce debuga o codigo.

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio já consegui resolver esse problema, apaguei a lista que tinha criado, nao preciso dela. Em vez disso, fiz um try catch e funcionou

Comment: Então beleza cara, desculpa noa ter ajudado mais, porem posta ai sua solução e marca ela como resposta para os demais usuários analisarem o que foi feito quem sabe não ajuda alguém no futuro

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio ajudou o bastante ! Muito obrigado, vou postar como ficou o código e como ele está a funcionar !

Comment: Você disse noutro comentário que: "Eu tenho um ficheiro xml com informações de produtos (o group é uma delas) e uso um foreach para percorrer todos os produtos e a cada foreach a variável toma valores diferentes." Então existe uma lista de Codes que voce verifica. Uma lista de objetos com essa propriedade. Acho que tu poderia pensar em adicionar essa lista no where do select pra not in e fazer o foreach só do que sobra.  Só sugestão. Como tu aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Alterei o código assim, com um ***try catch*** e funcionou:

```
conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Code FROM ArticleFamily", conn);
                SqlDataReader rd3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd3.HasRows)
                {
                    rd3.Read();
                    if (group != rd3["Code"].ToString())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                            conn.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO ArticleFamily(Code, [Desc], IsDefault, IsToWeb, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted, Margin, IsPOSVisible, IsWithArticleCodePrefix, ArticleCodePrefix, ExternalCode, IsSubFamilyRequired)
                                                         VALUES (@code, 'DESCRIÇÃO', 0, 0, 1, @date, 1, @date, 0, 0, 1, 1, @code, 1, 0)", conn);
                            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", group);
                            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
```